# I want to customize profile edit with some additional fields on database(users table) in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, user-profile

I tried to override `profile.xml` file along with `edit.php` (view file) by placing them within `templates/template_name/html/com_users/profile folder`, and also made sure the `edit.php` file know about new `profile.xml ($this->form->loadFile( dirname(__FILE__) . DS . "profile.xml");)` but i cant seem to make it work while updating custom fields from profile editing page at the front end. Also i can see that custom fields are not in order as it should be with respect to `profile.xml`. Please somebody help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can't override an Joomla xml file. You need to create a user plugin to install separately for the form fields to appear. There is a profile plugin that comes with the default Joomla installation. Further details on this can be found [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin).